# Database Search that Compares Results for Mutiple Seach Keywords

Tags: sql, database, search

Fist, let me say I know very little about SQL language and am trying to learn (albeit very slowly). I have created a database table with columns for

```
ECOREGION_ID  
ECOREGION_NAME 
SPECIES_NAME 
CLASS
```

so that there is one row for each species name in each ecoregion. My end goal is to create a form in which I can enter in multiple species names and search for the ecoregions they share. For example, if I enter into the 4 different search boxes "Tiger", "Red Panda", "Sloth Bear", and "Rhino" it would bring up a list of all the Ecoregions in which these four species share. I am wondering a few things:

1. Is my data set up in the correct way in order to do this or is there a more efficient way to set i t up?
2. What statement should I use to create an sql statement to perform the search I want?
3. What is the technical term for what I am wanting to do?  I have tried many different searches on different forums and can't seem to find what I am looking for, mostly because I probably don't know what to search, lol.

Thanks,

-Drew

Answer (score 0):

You have ECORegion_ID and ECORegion_Name in the same table.   I would suggest create a separate table to hold ECORegions.   This table would have both an ID and Name.   The search table would then only have the ECORegion_ID.   This process is called normalization.   It basically reduces redundant data in your database.

You are looking for a **SELECT** statement, which is used to pull data out of one or more tables.  The statement has a WHERE option to restrict which rows you bring back and an IN expression as part of the WHERE to allow you to look for multiple keywords.

Search for Normalization to see why to put region name in a separate table.   Look up SQL Select to get syntax for the select statement you should get off to a good start

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the original database that I downloaded has all this information in multiple tables (normalized), as a novice I thought it was more complicated than it had to be and joined these things together, lol,  OOPS!  Is there a good tutorial on how to set up the form (with keyword search box, search results box, ect.).  Would I eventually need to create a macro to perform the search.  I would like the process to be more automated so I can pull up this info for clients and not have to write a select statement every time I want to look something up.  Thanks again.

Comment: A lot depends on the database software and the programming language.  There are a lot of choices.   Do you use Windows?  If you can give some background on your type of environment, I can point you to a few tutorials

Comment: I am using Open Office Base 4.1.1 on Windows 7